# Total derivation

Tags: calculus

> $$\pi_1(p_2)=\max_{x_1}p_1(x_1;p_2)x_1-MC_{x_1}x_1.\tag{2}$$
>   The first order condition is $$\phi(x_1;p_2)=\dfrac{\partial p_1}{\partial x_1}(x_1;p_2)x_1+p_1(x_1;p_2)-MC_{x_1}=0$$ and the second order condition requires that $\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x_1^2}<0$. Write the monopoly quantity as a function of the price of good $2:x_1^m(p_2)$. Take the total derivative of the first order condition to establish that $$\dfrac{\partial x_1^m(p_2)}{\partial p_2}=-\dfrac{\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_1\partial p_2}}
> {\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x_1^2}}=-\dfrac
> {\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial x_1\partial p_2}x_1^m+\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial p_2}}
> {\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x_1^2}}
> \tag3$$ 
>   We assume that $\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial p_2}\gt0$ so $\frac{\partial x_1^m (p_2)}{\partial p_2}$ is positive if $\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial x_1\partial p_2}$ is positive or not too negative (this is controlling what happens to the slope of the inverse demand curve - if it is linear, then this will be zero). We assume that this is the case so that $\frac{\partial x_1^m(p_2)}{\partial p_2}\gt0$. The maximized profit of the monopolist is $\pi_1(p_2)$ and it is an increasing function of $p_2$ when $\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial p_2}\gt0$.

I don't quite understand how to get equation $(3)$ from equation $(2)$, and I suspect there is something wrong with my professor's notes. Please help! Thanks a lot!